# Test Case Structure

Tags: selenium, web, webdriver, driver, testng

I am working on a Selenium project and have certain doubts in coverting a Manual Test case into a Selenium Test Script.

Assume I have 2 Test case as follows,
First case:
1. NAvigate to GMAIL
2. Login to Gmail with valid username and password
3. Check Inbox for New Emails.
4. Read the email
5. Signout

Second case:
1. NAvigate to GMAIL
2. Login to Gmail with valid username and password
3. Compose an email
4. send the email
5. Signout

**My DOUBTS**

1. Is each Test case is one Class in Java ?
2. Is Each test Step is a method in java ?

Thanks, some inputs would help me.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on the complexity and usability of your java-selenium code.

**Is each Test case is one Class in Java ?**

---> In this case, you can write a method for login functinality, where you will pass username and password as arguments to that method. This method can be called inside any class(any class you are writing to test any other test case also) whenever you need to login.

So, a test case can be a class. If it is a single class, it will be helpful for debugging and maintaining purpose. If the test case is too complex, you can split the functionlity into two classes or more.

**Is Each test Step is a method in java ?**

---> Yes, it can be. when you are checking the login or signout functionality, you will be calling login method or signout method respectively. Sometimes, if the method cannot be reused and it is specific to an application only, then it will not be a method. You need to explicitly write all the logic instead of calling the already existing method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Liked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's based on your requirement.

example

```
public class gmailTest()
{

   @BeforeClass
   public void beforeClass()
   {
       1. Navigate to Gmail
       2. sign in
   }

   @BeforeMethod
   public void beforeMethod()
   {

   }
   @Test
   public void testInbox()
   {
        Check Inbox for New Emails , Read the email 
   }
   @Test
   public void testInbox()
   {
        Compose an email , send the email
   }
    @AfterMethod
   public void afterMethod()
   {

   }
   @BeforeClass
   public void afterClass()
   {
      signout
   }

}
```

**@BeforeClass:** The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.

**@AfterClass:** The annotated method will be run after all the test methods in the current class have been run.

**@BeforeMethod:** The annotated method will be run before each test method.

**@AfterMethod:** The annotated method will be run after each test method.

For more info regarding testng click [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: If the cases need to be run in parallel, the above solution may fail.

Comment: if tests needed to be run in parallel , how the implementation should be ? What if I need to make two instance of one test case but with different data ?

Comment: You can use TestNG's dataprovider or factory.  Refer http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Answer (score 0):

I once had the exact same problem (but I'm using Python).
So this is what I've done:

1) Each `class` is the **Test Case**
2) Each `method` is a **Test Step**
3) Within the `class` *setup* and *tear down* completely to the initial point. (So it can be used for distribution later)
4) Create the logic of "if one method fails -> the rest of the methods in the class are not run (failed automatically)"

5) (!!) create the logic of "if the method changes the *state* then add a 'tear down' for it"